# Как запустить selenium с vpn?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, vpn

Мне нужно получить доступ к Крымскому сайту который в России не работает..

Соответственно сайт без впн не работает.

Пробовал запускать с путем до файла расширения впн, а также с запуском профиля в котором оно уже установлено, но все попытки были тщетны.

Запуск через профиль:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

user_data_dir = r"C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 3"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\New\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument("profile-directory=Profile 3")

chromedriver = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = Chrome(service=chromedriver, options=options)

driver.get('https://md-crimea.ru')
```

Получаю следующую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\crimea_is_ours.py", line 19, in <module>
    driver = Chrome(service=chromedriver, options=options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 207, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Projects\Selenium\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
        GetHandleVerifier [0x008972A3+45731]
        (No symbol) [0x00822D51]
        (No symbol) [0x0071880D]
        (No symbol) [0x0073DE89]
        (No symbol) [0x0073A310]
        (No symbol) [0x0076EB26]
        (No symbol) [0x0076E6BC]
        (No symbol) [0x00767DD6]
        (No symbol) [0x007431F6]
        (No symbol) [0x0074439D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BA0716+3229462]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BE84C8+3523784]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00BE214C+3498316]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00921680+611968]
        (No symbol) [0x0082CCCC]
        (No symbol) [0x00828DF8]
        (No symbol) [0x00828F1D]
        (No symbol) [0x0081B2C7]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75A77BA9+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x7729BD3B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x7729BCBF+191]
```

Следующая попытка была запуск через путь указывающий на расширение vpn:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

vpn_extension_path = r"C:\Users\New\AppData\Local\Yandex\YandexBrowser\User Data\Default\Extensions\ekmmelpnmfdegjhnmadddcfjcahpajnm\1.193.344_0"

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--load-extension={}'.format(vpn_extension_path))
chromedriver = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = Chrome(service=chromedriver, options=options)

driver.get('https://md-crimea.ru')
```

Браузер запускается с расширением, я его включаю и вроде как всё хорошо, но в консоль выводится следующее:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58252/devtools/browser/17aec7dd-196e-4891-829b-aa9f539939d4
[14932:18348:1104/013603.774:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013603.775:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013604.056:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013604.056:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[10380:17836:1104/013604.083:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(702)] Message 0 rejected by interface blink.mojom.WidgetHost
[14932:18348:1104/013604.804:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013605.052:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013605.076:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013605.304:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013615.655:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013615.834:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013615.862:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013616.106:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013616.247:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013616.247:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013616.330:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013616.494:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013621.389:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013621.641:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013621.819:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013621.919:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013622.199:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013622.357:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(975)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -101
[14932:18348:1104/013627.256:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013627.258:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013627.259:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013628.043:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013628.589:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013628.591:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013628.591:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013629.187:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
[14932:18348:1104/013640.195:ERROR:tcp_socket_win.cc(876)] connect failed: 10049
```

Как решить данную ситуацию ?